# Finding object in array initial state React-Redux app

Tags: react-redux

I am currently working on an app that **do not support server rendering**, so i have to have an empty state when the client loads the app. Then a fetch is dispatched and the **state is soon updated**.

I have a component (some kind of editor) which should **find an object** based on a url-parameter. My mapStateToProps function looks something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    book: state.library.list.find(function(book){ return book.id === ownProps.params.book_id})
  }
}
```

this.props.book is undefined when the component runs getInitialState, so it does not get the update when the state is fetched. I get the following error in the console of my browser when the component loads:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.book.title')
```

From there on the editor remains empty, even when the state is received from the server later on.

Any idea of how i can solve this problem?

Comment: In your reducer you need to initialize the state. You will have something like: `const initState = {vendors: [],selectedVendor: null}; const findBookReducer = (state = initState, action) => {`

Comment: So you suggest i put the editor's state in the redux store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution: Preload the store on the server

I finally found an answer to my problem. What i did, was to check upon every request if the user was logged in (through JSON web tokens). If the user was logged in, i **preloaded the state** and sent it with the first request (assigned it to window._PRELOADED_STATE_ with a *script* tag in the response string).

Then i also added two lines on the client code

```
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
const store = createStore( rootReducer, preloadedState, applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware, thunkMiddleware) );
```

then the store was updated before the editor component asked for it.

This solution is based on some ideas introduced at redux's home page http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put a watch when you are loading data from `this.props.book` to not be an undefined

```
if(this.props.book) {
  //do something with this.props.book
}
```

Comment: But the component's state is only set on getInitialState? The editor needs to have the book's content in it's state, so this would require me to have the editor's state in the redux store?

Comment: You can also set initial state of every reducer, so set library or whatever to be empty array as an initial state, and then you can look up to see if the array is empty, or better just set it to null and you can check for it as I mentioned in my answer